# How can I filter select list options based on foreach observablearray property

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a `foreach` that uses an observablearray called `CertificateDetailsToShow`.  `CertificateDetailsToShow` has a column called `LoanNum`.  Nested in the foreach, I have a select list that uses an observablearray called `DDABankNum`s (populates the select list options).  It has a property called `mLoanNum`.  I want to filter what is displayed in the select list based on the `LoanNum` from both observablearrays (`DDABankNums.mLoanNum = CertificateDetailsToShow.LoanNum`).  How can I do that?

My view code-

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CertificateDetailsToShow">
  <tr id="Tr1" style="cursor: pointer">
    <td>
      <ul style="width: 100%">
        <h5 class="muted"><b>Loan:&nbsp;<span class="muted" data-bind="text: LoanNum"></span>&nbsp;(<span data-bind="    text: CurrType"></span>)</b>
          <select id="Select1" style="margin-top: 0px; height: 24px; width: 160px !important"
            data-bind="options: $parent.DDABankNums, optionsText: 'AccountName', value: $parent.mLoanNum, optionsCaption: $data.LoanNum">
          </select>
        </h5>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: CertificateDetailsToShow">
  <tr>
    <td>
      Loan: <span data-bind="text: LoanNum"></span> (<span data-bind="text: CurrType"></span>)

      <select
        data-bind="options: $parent.filter($parent.DDABankNums, $data.LoanNum), optionsText: 'AccountName', optionsValue: 'myDDABankNumValueAttributeName'">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

ViewModel contains this method:

```
self.filter = function(ddaBankNums, loanNum) {
    return ddaBankNums().filter(function(ddaBankNum) {
         return ddaBankNum.mLoanNum == loanNum;
    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing showing still on the view after changing to your code above.  ddaBankNum contains 20 items, loanNum comes in ok, but the drop down contains no data.  It should match on the loanNum and display approx 2 records in each drop down list, but it doesn't.  Ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: I changed my answer to match property names you give in your explanation: DDBankNum has property "mLoanNum" and CertificateDetailsToShow has property "LoanNum".

Comment: Got It!  Thanks Hallvar.  One modification I had to make was instead of return ddaBankNums.filter(function(ddaBankNum), i used return DDABankNums().filter(function (ddaBankNum) and it worked.